# Android smack 4.1 flooded with offline messages ejabberd

Tags: android, erlang, ejabberd

I am working on chat app by using smack 4.1 and ejabberd-15.11 my scenario is -
if client A,B,C,D send messages to E and E is offline  then all messages stores in offline storage but when user E comes online android client becomes unresponsive if number of offline stored messages are in huge amount (3000-5000). Please suggest me some solution

Comment: in my scenarion offline message are received by FCM but also repeate those all message from ejabbered when client send available status . Any  idea  ?

Comment: how you are receiving messages from client by  XEP-0013: Flexible offline messages retrieval or send user presence  and server start sending messages ? explain your client  flow.

Comment: sending available and unavailable status when need to do online and offline

Answer (score 1):

The default setting in ejabberd example config file is to limit the number of offline messages to 100.

```
  max_user_offline_messages: 
    admin: 5000
    all: 100
```

New messages will be rejected and sender will be notified with an error.

If you user is an admin but you are expecting to connect as admin from Android, you can also configured ejabberd to limit the number of offline messages for admin to 100 messages.

Comment: but i want to large amount of offline messages.Is there is way to develop custom module to handle offline messages? Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: In XMPP, you will then have to download them all on login and then your connection will be irresponsive if you are on a slow connection. If you want to avoid downloading them, then you need to implement XEP-0013: Flexible offline messages retrieval. It is not yet supported by ejabberd, but you can add it as code is open source.

Comment: Yes i can develop custom module over ejabberd  for Flexible offline messages retrieval but i have no idea from where to start .Please guide me.

Comment: You should start learning basic module developments. Try building a filter or echo module for example.